# How do you calculate caps for voltage regulator circuit

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, voltage-regulator

In a voltage regulator circuit, how do you calculate which capacitors are placed before and after the regulator?

For example, if I'm pulling 50mA from a 5VDC regulator(L78M05) with a 9V input, how do I determine which caps are going to give me the least amount of ripple?
 [image: Example regulator]

Comment: Read the datasheet of the regulator.  In your case, since neither the battery nor the LED will cause any ripple you'll be fine with whatever it proposes (and 78xx are benign compared to LDOs).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a wide latitude.  In a big enough design where I'm using various size caps already, I usually use 10 µF on the input of such a regulator and 1 µF on the output.  You can get away with a lot less, but there is little harm to having more, especially on the input where more is better from the regulator point of view.

The cap values have little to do with current, since for a ideal regulator and battery the voltages on them would not change.  The purpose is to make the lines look low impedance at frequencies high enough that the active circuitry can't handle.  The output cap is also part of the feedback loop of the regulator, and different regulators have different requirements.  A 7805 will be fine with 1 µF ceramic close to its output pins.  Other regulators may have specific requirements, including some *minimum* ESR for some of the older low-dropout types.

So the real answer is to read the datasheet and make sure you meet all the input and output cap requirements.

Answer (score -1):

The larger the capacitor, the less the ripple.  As an analogy, think of the capacitor as a water storage tank.  The larger the water tank, the less impact drawing water from it will have on the water level.  The ocean is an effectively infinite capacitor, so when water leaves the ocean, the water level doesn't change hardly at all. Also, you can see from the equation that the higher the load resistance, the less ripple.  That's pretty obvious because the higher the resistance, the less current it will draw.

But obviously, you can't just throw in a massive capacitor.  You should read the datasheet for your regulator to see what it suggests.

Comment: Which equation are you referring to?

Comment: Sorry, I originally referenced an equation for voltage ripple off a full-wave rectifier.  Take a look at this page.

http://www.electroschematics.com/7048/capacitor-input-filter-calculation/

Since you don't have a full-wave rectifier, it doesn't exactly apply.  Still though, the principle should still be true that a larger capacitor will mitigate ripple more than a smaller one.  Have a look at where the author solves for delta_v on that page, and you'll see that C is in the denominator.  Thus, a larger capacitance means less ripple.

Comment: Generally though, ripple only happens with AC sources.  I've never really heard of ripple happening with a battery, and I can't imagine any internal characteristics of a battery that would cause it to behave like a fluctuating input source.  Unless you are talking about load regulation, where your load  may be having variations on how much current it draws.  It looks like in that circuit though you are just lighting an LED.  That won't have any sort of ripple or variation.

Comment: In my case, I'm powering a ATMEGA328P-AU and I want to give it the cleanest signal I can to get stable reads from the ADC channels.  The input would be a 9VDC wall wart and the output would be 5VDC.  The MCU would average around 50mA.

Comment: Capacitors as water tanks is a temping but very poor [mental model of a capacitor](http://amasci.com/emotor/cap1.html). In a hydraulic analogy, real capacitors have no air in them, and it's not possible to put some water in without taking an equal amount of water out. Tanks aren't like this, leading people to nonsense like current can't flow through capacitors, or batteries produce charge.

Comment: @PhilFrost   Usually, when I hear people refer to water analogies for electrical components, and when I do myself, it is only meant to be related to a specific characteristic of the analgous counterpart.  In this case, the water level is analgous to the voltage level.  Because often times, we aren't concerned with understanding exactly how the component works, just a part of it.  I agree that that analogy is much more accurate to the real component, but I can't agree that it's better in this case, because it doesn't convey as well of a visual comparison to voltage level as water level does.

Comment: @PhilFrost In the sphere analogy, energy is stored in the rubber plate, and more capacitance means it can store more energy, so the plate can be bent further.  Now I have to think about how far plates bend, and how much do they bend back when energy is removed.  At least for me, this is much more confusing that just "a larger water tank requires more water drawn from it to affect the height of the water level than a smaller one does.  Not only that, water level is something people are very familiar with.  I'm willing to bet most people unfamiliar with electronics would prefer the water one.

Comment: @krb686 A larger capacitance *does not* mean it can store more energy. A larger capacitance means voltage changes more slowly if current is held constant. That says nothing about how much energy the capacitor can store, and in fact, given two ideal capacitors of different sizes that don't break down at some voltage limit, I can store just as much energy in either one. The difference will be that for the same stored energy, the voltage across the smaller capacitor will be greater, and the charge lesser, which is evident from \$C=q/V\$.

Comment: @PhilFrost Sorry, I should have explicitly stated that voltage is held constant.  That was implied.  So given a similar potential difference across the plates, the amount of stored energy in a capacitor with higher capacitance will be greater than that of a capacitor with less capacitance.  That assumption is especially relevant to this question, __a voltage regulator__.

Comment: @PhilFrost And from your equation, V = q/C, so delta_v = delta_q/C.  Thus, for a similar amount of "charge" removed from a capacitor, or energy removed, the change in voltage will be less on one with higher capacitance.

Comment: @krb686 indeed, which would make a very good answer, because it doesn't introduce a flawed and harmful analogy.

Comment: Well that depends on how you look at it. For instance, the analogy can be perceived as the **energy stored** in the capacitor is analogous to the water level in the tank, in which case it makes perfect sense, because more energy can be extracted in one with higher capacitance while retaining a certain voltage level.  This is how I have naturally always thought about it and many other people I know too.  It's one thing to create an analogy to precisely understand how something works, and another to create an analogy effective and relevant to what it is used for in its own domain.

Comment: Regardless, this little ramble has gone off topic for a while.  @JustinManuel, you are saying you want the cleanest possible power source (9v) without any ripple?